# Jupyter notebook set project dependency

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I have two different project folders. I want to make one of the projects a root so that when I import something from first project in the second project it does not show `ModuleNotFoundError`. For example, In PyCharm we can set project dependencies. Is there way to do so in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this in notebooks or jupyterlab would be to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable. For example, on MAC or unix-based OS, using bash, do this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/project"
```

Then re-load the notebook. Adding your project path to the `PYTHONPATH` variable will allow you to import any modules that are specified in this variable.

Additionally, you can set this variable in a jupyter notebook itself by entering the bash command into a notebook cell, prepended with the `!` symbol like this:

```sh
! export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/project"
```

Then executing the cell.

Comment: thanks for comment. But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 10 i am using